# KubeletNotReady - Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo

Tags: kubernetes

I m having below error while installing Kubernetes cluster in Ubunutu 18.04. Kubernetes master is ready. I' m using flannel as pod network. I m going to add my first node to the cluster using join command.

```
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 05:43:02 +0000   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 05:38:47 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 05:43:02 +0000   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 05:38:47 +0000   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 05:43:02 +0000   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 05:38:47 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 05:43:02 +0000   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 05:38:47 +0000   KubeletNotReady              Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condition; caused by: the server could not find the requested resource
```

Update:

I noticed below in worker node

```
    root@worker02:~# systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-12-11 06:47:41 UTC; 27s ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
 Main PID: 14247 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 14 (limit: 2295)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─14247 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --cgroup-driv

Dec 11 06:47:43 worker02 kubelet[14247]: I1211 06:47:43.085292   14247 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "flannel-cfg" (UniqueName: "kuber
Dec 11 06:47:43 worker02 kubelet[14247]: I1211 06:47:43.086115   14247 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "flannel-token-nbss2" (UniqueName
Dec 11 06:47:43 worker02 kubelet[14247]: I1211 06:47:43.087975   14247 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "kube-proxy" (UniqueName: "kubern
Dec 11 06:47:43 worker02 kubelet[14247]: I1211 06:47:43.088104   14247 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "xtables-lock" (UniqueName: "kube
Dec 11 06:47:43 worker02 kubelet[14247]: I1211 06:47:43.088153   14247 reconciler.go:156] Reconciler: start to sync state
Dec 11 06:47:45 worker02 kubelet[14247]: E1211 06:47:45.130889   14247 csi_plugin.go:267] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condit
Dec 11 06:47:48 worker02 kubelet[14247]: E1211 06:47:48.134042   14247 csi_plugin.go:267] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condit
Dec 11 06:47:50 worker02 kubelet[14247]: E1211 06:47:50.538096   14247 csi_plugin.go:267] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condit
Dec 11 06:47:53 worker02 kubelet[14247]: E1211 06:47:53.131425   14247 csi_plugin.go:267] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condit
Dec 11 06:47:56 worker02 kubelet[14247]: E1211 06:47:56.840529   14247 csi_plugin.go:267] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condit
```

Please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you mean flannel for pod network?

Comment: yes. i m using flannel as pod network

Comment: did you turn off your swap memory

Comment: yes. i have turn off swap memory using, swapoff -a

Comment: Did you add your node IP and names under /etc/hosts

Comment: nope. i didn't put aanything in host files

Comment: How are you installing your master?

Comment: As per my understanding she is using kubeadm for installation

Comment: i was using below commands:sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 and kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/2140ac876ef134e0ed5af15c65e414cf26827915/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

Comment: this link can help you 

https://medium.com/@naveenkulkarni029/steps-to-install-kubernetes-in-an-on-premise-ubuntu-gpu-server-2915baa8f04c

Comment: that like i only for 1 cluster with 1 master node. If you want to added worker nodes. You need to specify your IP and name of the machine in /etc/hosts file of your master node. Then instatiate your kubernetes master. Once it is started. Then join your worker nodes to the master. Make sure you install kubectl, and docker in your worker node. If you want the master only to manage kubernetes cluster then please skip step 26 of the link shared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Link to install Kubernetes](https://medium.com/@naveenkulkarni029/steps-to-install-kubernetes-in-an-on-premise-ubuntu-gpu-server-2915baa8f04c)

This link is only for 1 cluster with 1 master node. If you want to added worker nodes. You need to specify your IP and name of the machine in /etc/hosts file of your master node. Then instatiate your kubernetes master. Once it is started. Then join your worker nodes to the master. Make sure you install kubectl, and docker in your worker node. If you want the master only to manage kubernetes cluster then please skip step 26 of the link shared.

Comment: It worked, i have missed to install kubernetes-cni in master node

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue, however, my situation is that I have a running k8s cluster, and suddenly, the CISNodeInfo issue happened on some of my k8s node, and the node not in the cluster anymore. Search with google for some days, finally get the answer from 
[Node cannot join #86094](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/86094)

Just editing /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml to add:

```
featureGates:
  CSIMigration: false
```

... at the end of the file seemed to allow the cluster to start as expected.